# Minimum Depth Of Binary Tree Python Not Working

Tags: python, binary-tree

I am trying to solve a problem that requires finding the minimum depth of a binary tree. I can't seem to find the error. Any advice would be of great help.

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
    def minDepth(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
        if not root:
            return 0
        
        queue = []
        queue = collections.deque(queue)
        queue.append(root)
        depth = 0
        
        while len(queue) != 0:
            numberOfNodes = len(queue)
            
            while numberOfNodes > 0:
                currentNode = queue.popleft()
                
                if not currentNode and not currentNode:
                    depth += 1
                    return depth
                
                if currentNode.left:
                    queue.append(currentNode.left)
                
                if currentNode.right:
                    queue.append(currentNode.right)
                
                numberOfNodes -= 1
            
            depth += 1
        return depth
```

Comment: Is `if not currentNode and not currentNode:` a typo? I think it should be `if not currentNode.left and not currentNode.right:`

Comment: What a mistake I've made. Forgot to add left and right. Thank you so much for saving my time.

Comment: Haha, no worries. It happens to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the slight error. In place of :

```
if not currentNode and not currentNode:
    depth += 1
    return depth
```

Maybe, it should be this:

```
if currentnode.left is None and currentnode.right is None:     
    return depth
```